# Can I have 2 RPi devices deliver the same WiFi name as main WiFi box?

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless, windows

I have a full Windows domain controller that provides the Ethernet network for the house, including DHCP, DNS, and NAT to the Internet. We also have an old Apple AirPort providing our main WiFi network. I have two (2) Raspberry Pi devices one RPi2 one RPi3, and I have **successfully** bridged them so they can deliver WiFi to the hard-to-reach places in the house, but I've given them unique WiFi names. They each have different static IP addresses, and I am currently using the /etc/network/interfaces config file.

I would like to have these 2 RPis offer the same network name as the main WiFi; is it possible to change the configuration to match the WiFi name and password without interference? I imagine so, but I wasn't sure whether anyone else had tried this.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any two routers with the same name and password as you please. I do not believe that your client would automatically connect to the second router if it originally signed in with the first. As the wifi standard only has the password sent to the router the first time it is used, after that a session token is used. So let's imagine that you logged in with your phone to the first router, a session key was generated, everything was working fine. Then you walked over to the next room and your phone attempted to connect to the second router. Well that connection would be denied as the second router will not have the session key stored on it so it will not be able to authenticate your phone as having properly logged in. This is why large businesses and schools use enterprise grade products offered by large companies like Cisco. It's because they offer software and servers that allow for the sharing of session keys across routers. Now I'm not saying that you wouldn't be able to set something up like this yourself I'm simply saying that you won't find much help online as most people aren't using the Pi and that it is more difficult than you think.

Comment: OK, it sounds like my initial impulse to give each Pi its own name was the right one. It only takes a minute to add each network to each device we use in the house. My experience so far has been that as we move from room to room we can prompt our device to pick up on the nearer, stronger signal, or the device itself does the swap. 

I may continue to dig into a way to share session tokens -- sounds like an interesting project in my (hah!) spare time. Thanks Mohammad.

Comment: @Toolie no problem, most devices(basically all) will auto connect to the router with the strongest signal regardless of name. Also if this answer has helped you please feel free to mark it as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer to give me a few points as I have done for you by liking your question